# SetText not working for more than the first textBox

Tags: blackberry, textbox

I am using a custom textbox field,and am trying to change the text programmatically using setText...
It's working for the first field, but not for the second field...
Could someone help me out here...the text to be set is getting sent into the custom textbox , but the edit field.settext works only for the first instance of the textbox...

I can't post the code right now, but will try to give a better understanding-
I have 4 text boxes in one page,with a key listener added to the page.( this is to facilitate transliteration-English to Gujarati )
I added a int value to keep track of which field has focus, and used that to call set text method on the appropriate field.

The correct method gets called, with the correct value, and still only the first text box field's value gets reset...I used debug to follow the flow, right upto the point where the edit field.setText gets executed.

I tried the same with simple edit fields instead of custom fields, and got the same result...

The setText gets executed properly when the keylistener is not active though...
So I am stumped as to what is causing the problem.
Will add the keylistener code and any other relevant code by the day end.

Comment: How can we suggest you anything without looking at your code, paste some code here.

Comment: Sorry bout that,posting from my iPad . Will add the code ASAP.

Comment: We solved the issue by having separate keylisteners for each textbox. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, with the death of blackberry, this is not really going to help anyone, but at the same time , this question has been open for 2 years, so i decided to close it :-)
We solved the issue by having separate keylisteners for each textbox. Thank you for the assistance. –

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
  {
    TextField tempTextBox;
  public MyScreen()
 {        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle");
    tempTextBox = new TextField("Titile: ", "Fitst Detail");
    this.add(tempTextBox);

    tempTextBox.setText("Second text");

    tempTextBox.setText("Third Text");

}
```

}

if not refresh screen then you can set

```
invalidate();
```

after serText method.

hope help full.